# Remove unwanted panels from SilverStripe Dashboard Module

Tags: silverstripe

I'm using the [dashboard](https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-dashboard) module but don't want my users to be able to select any kind of panel. Is there a way to remove panels like "Weather" or "Google Analytics" from the available panels list without deleting the whole class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dashboard module has [recently been updated](https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-dashboard/pull/75) to allow the enabling and disabling of panels through a yml config file such as `mysite/_config/config.yml`.

The following rule will disable the `DashboardGoogleAnalyticsPanel`:

```
DashboardGoogleAnalyticsPanel:
  enabled: false
```

The following rule will disable all panels and enable the `CustomPanel`:

```
DashboardPanel:
  enabled: false

CustomPanel:
  enabled: true
```

Comment: but the user should be able to add only specific panels. All off/on is not what I need ;)

Comment: @csy_dot_io I have changed my answer with a better way to do this through a `config.yml` file. If you would like to try this method make sure you update your Dashboard module to the latest version.

Comment: Thank's. I've followed the process on github. And already made the update

Answer (score 3):

Not a real solution, more a workaround. But it does what it should.

```
  $("[data-create-url*='DashboardRSSFeedPanel'], [data-create-url*='DashboardGoogleAnalyticsPanel'], [data-create-url*='DashboardGridFieldPanel'], [data-create-url*='DashboardModelAdminPanel'], [data-create-url*='DashboardSectionEditorPanel'], [data-create-url*='DashboardWeatherPanel'], [data-create-url*='DashboardRecentEditsPanel']").entwine({
    onmatch: function() {
      $(this).remove();
      $('.available-panel').removeClass('even');
      $('.available-panel').removeClass('odd');
      $('.available-panel:even').addClass('odd');
      $('.available-panel:odd').addClass('even');
    }
  });
```